# Is it possible to define the amount of arguments in a function with variable number of arguments by a global variable

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I want to define a function with variable amount of arguments, where this amount should be fixed by a global variable, say `N`, and I thought of using a va_list to achieve that. Is it possible to declare that function without any reference to the number of arguments, thus without having to enter `N` as the first variable when calling it, but only the rest of them? If not, is there a way other than using a va_list to do this?

Now I just declared it according to the standard way and in its definition I assign the value of `N` to the first argument of that function (so that, no matter which integer one uses as first argument, it always has the desired value). Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: A couple questions: Are all of these arguments supposed to be of the same type?  Is `N` a compile-time constant or can the user set it?  If they're the same type `T` and `N` is a compile-time constant, then I recommend `std::array<T, N>`.  In general I would recommend against `std::va_list`.

Comment: Wait, here's a better question: what is your goal in having a variable number of arguments?  There are a lot of possibilities and each have a safer solution than `std::va_list`.

Comment: Yes, they are of the same type (user-defined) and, for the moment, `N` is a compile time constant (of type `int`) but I intend to change it to a run-time assignable when the code develops a little further. Does this affect the utility of `std::array<T,N>` ?

Comment: I want to initialize a vector. The dimension and the underlying field of the vector space it lies in should be user-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max66's is the correct answer to the original question: how to have a variable number of arguments and constrain the number of arguments.

However, the number of function arguments sits squarely in the world of compile-time.  What you probably want is a *single* argument of type `std::vector`.  `std::vector` contains a variable number of values of the same type.  If you want to set at runtime what that length should always be, then you probably want to check the length and throw an exception if it's wrong.

```
size_t N__ = 4;

int sum(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
  if (vec.size() != N__) { throw std::length_error("error message"); }
  int out = 0;
  for (int i_ : vec) { out += i_; }
  return out;
}
```

And then you can call that with

```
const int just_ten = sum({1, 2, 3, 4});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what do you want.

But if you can use at least C++11, and if you accept to use variadic templates for variable amounts of arguments, I propose the use of SFINAE to impose that the variable number of arguments is exaclty `N`

The following is a full working example

```
#include <type_traits>

static constexpr std::size_t N = 3U;

template <typename ... Args>
typename std::enable_if<N == sizeof...(Args), int>::type foo (Args ... as)
 { return 0; }

int main ()
 {
   //foo(0, 1);       // compilation error
   foo(0, 1, 2);    // compile
   //foo(0, 1, 2, 3); // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: Thank's for the example but, for the moment, it looks too advanced to me (I am still a C++ newbie). Perhaps I could make use of it after some months!

Comment: @user3257624 - I see... but if you're a newbie in C++, I give you a suggestion: if you can use at least C++11, avoid old C-style way for variadic number of arguments and use template variadic.